# Multipart Form Data Request Failing to Call For Large File Sizes

Tags: c#, file-upload, multipartform-data, large-files

I have a file upload function that takes a multipart form data request and puts the file in AWS. IT's working fine for small files, but fails when the file gets very large. (haven't tested exactly how big, but we want to be able to handle any size).

Here's the Linqpad script I'm using to test upload:

```
const string filePath = @"C:\Users\josh.bowdish\Pictures\SmallFile.png";
const string contentType = "image/png";

//const string filePath = @"C:\Users\josh.bowdish\Pictures\ReallyBigFile.mp4";
//const string contentType = "video/mp4";

using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

    form.Add(new ByteArrayContent(bytes)
    {
        Headers =
        {
            ContentLength = bytes.Length,
            ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue(contentType)
        }
    },"notused","not.used");

    using (var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("http://localhost:52655/api/Storage/UploadAttachment", form))
    {
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        response.Content.Dump();
    }
}
```

The SmallFile.png uploads just fine, but ReallyBigFile.mp4 doesn't even hit my local service. It does get me a 404 error though, which doesn't make sense to me because the Service endpoint doesn't change. 
[image]I'd post the receiving method's code (api/Storage/UploadAttachment), but attempting to call it with the large file doesn't even hit my first breakpoint just inside the method call.

My googling efforts haven't returned very much of use as of yet. Any guidance would be much appreciated! Please let me know if there's anything else I can provide to help figure it out!

Thanks,

~Josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting a 404 on larger files but not smaller files, ensure your web config settings allows for large files:

```
<!-- maxRequestLength in kilobytes -->
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1000000" />
</system.web>

<!-- maxAllowedContentLength in bytes -->
<system.WebServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1000000000" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.WebServer>
```